# Is CSRF token vulnerable if CORS is enabled?

Tags: csrf, cors

Let's analyze the following scenario:

- User authenticates with `session` cookie
- I have `CORS` enabled (like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` - header)
- I use `CSRF Token` to prevent `CSRF` attacks and I include it in `HTML` document's body

Is it possible to perform CSRF attack like this?:
(Attack from domain: `attack.com`)

1. In `atack.dom/index.html` is written script that executes `GET` `mydomain.com` via e.g. `window.fetch`.
2. This script extracts `CSRF Token` from fetched `mydomain.com/index.html`
3. It performs then the real `CSRF` attack as it already has valid `CSRF Token` so it does attach this token to `<form>` and submit this prepared `<form>`

Is it possible? Is enabling CORS possibly making my wesbite vulnerable to CSRF attack despite the fact I'm using `CSRF Token` protection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you aren't using the same anti-CSRF token for authenticated and unauthenticated sessions, **no, you're fine**. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (abbreviated ACAO:*) only allows the caller to see the response if the request is made without "credentials" (cookies or HTTP authorization). Since your session token is in a cookie, either the server won't see it (and therefore should not return the victim's anti-CSRF token to the attacker), or the server will see it but the browser won't let the attacker see it (because the attacker sent the request "with credentials" and ACAO:* doesn't allow credentialed requests).

Note that even if you also use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, that doesn't change matters at all. ACAO:* overrides ACAC:true; a browser that conforms to the spec will ignore any ACAC header if it sees ACAO:*.

However, if rather than ACAO:*, you use ACAO:<origin the request comes from>, then that is extremely unsafe to combine with ACAC:true. That combination turns off most of same-origin policy for your website, allowing arbitrary sites to retrieve arbitrary content from your site within authenticated user sessions. The anti-CSRF token is part of that content, so an attacker would in that case be able to launch CSRF attacks easily.

Note also that if you *don't* have different anti-CSRF tokens for each session, then your anti-CSRF protection is broken with no need for CORS at all. An attacker can simply show up to the site, find the token, and use it CSRF a victim. Thus, it is essential that anti-CSRF tokens be unique for each user (and, if relevant, for each unauthenticated session where a user is nonetheless taking potentially-sensitive actions).

Comment: "a browser that conforms to the spec will ignore any ACAC header if it sees ACAO:*" Only if the request's `credentials` property is not `"include"`.

Comment: @jub0bs Not really. I should perhaps have said "a browser that conforms to the spec will *always treat ACAC as `false`, regardless of its presence or actual value, when the browser sees ACAO:\**". The presence or value of the ACAC header is ignored if ACAO:* is received. The browser will only let the script see the response for ACAO:* if credentials were not included in the request, but it will ignore any server-sent ACAC header either way.

Comment: What I was getting at is that "ignore" is too strong a word. In the particular case of a credentialed request, browsers raise an error if the response contains both `ACAO: *` and `ACAC: true`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentialsa

Comment: No, that's still wrong (overly specific). From your own link [(corrected)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials): there is no mention of ACAC at all. It's completely irrelevant, i.e. ignored. In the case of a credentialed request, browsers will *also* raise an error if ACAC: false, or if ACAC is not present at all. ACAO:* completely shadows ACAC (any value); it just does not matter in the least if ACAO:* is received.

Comment: You're right. I stand corrected. In Chromium, the error message is the same (regardless of the presence or value of `ACAC`) in case of a credentialed request to which the server replies with `ACAO: *`: *Access to fetch at 'REDACTEDB' from origin 'REDACTEDA' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '\*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the **CSRF token is in a response header** (`X-CSRF-Token`, say), the script will not be able to retrieve it, unless the `mydomain.com` resource contains an additional response header

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-CSRF-Token
```

So the proposed attack will fail in step 2.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header gives only access to the response body, but not to its headers.

If the **CSRF token is in the response body**, the script can access it, but the attack may still fail if the token is tied to a session cookie, because that session cookie is blocked as explained in the other answer.

Comment: But if the CSRF token is not included in header but in body (HTML form to be precise) (like Django framework does by default) then I'm vulnerable, right?